# Why result of Spark reduceByKey is not consistent

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to count the number of iteration of each line via spark using scala.
Following is my input:

1 vikram
2 sachin
3 shobit
4 alok
5 akul
5 akul
1 vikram
1 vikram
3 shobit
10 ashu
5 akul
1 vikram
2 sachin
7 vikram

now i create 2 separate RDDs as follows.

```
val f1 = sc.textFile("hdfs:///path to above data file")
val m1 = f1.map( s => (s.split(" ")(0),1) ) //creating a tuple (key,1)
//now if i create a RDD as
val rd1 = m1.reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b )
rd1.collect().foreach(println)
//I get a proper output i.e (it gives correct output every time)
//output: (4,1) (2,2) (7,1) (5,3) (3,2) (1,4) (10,1)

//but if i create a RDD as
val rd2 = m1.reduceByKey((a,b) => a+1 )
rd2.collect().foreach(println)
//I get a inconsistent result i.e some times i get this (WRONG)
//output: (4,1) (2,2) (7,1) (5,2) (3,2) (1,2) (10,1)
//and sometimes I get this as output (CORRECT)
//output: (4,1) (2,2) (7,1) (5,3) (3,2) (1,4) (10,1)
```

I am unable yo understand why is this happening and where to use what. I have also tried creating RDD as

```
val m2 = f1.map(s => (s,1))
val rd3 = m2.reduceByKey((a,b) => a+1 )
// Then also same issue occurs with a+1 but every thing works fine with a+b
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`reduceByKey` assumes the passed function is *commutative* and *associative* (as [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) clearly state).
And - your first function `(a, b) => a + b` *is*, but `(a, b) => a+1` *isn't*.

**WHY?**
For one thing - `reduceByKey` applies the supplied function to each *partition*, and then to the *combined results* of all partitions. In other words, `b` isn't always `1`, so using `a+1` simply isn't correct.

Think of the following scenario - the input contains 4 records, split into two partitions:

```
(aa, 1)
(aa, 1)

(aa, 1)
(cc, 1)
```

`reduceByKey(f)` on this input might be calculated as follows:

```
val intermediate1 = f((aa, 1), (aa, 1)) 
val intermediate2 = f((aa, 1), (cc, 1))

val result = f(intermediate2, intermediate1)
```

Now, let's follow this with `f = (a, b) => a + b`

```
val intermediate1 = f((aa, 1), (aa, 1))       // (aa, 2)
val intermediate2 = f((aa, 1), (cc, 1))       // (aa, 1), (cc, 1)

val result = f(intermediate2, intermediate1)  // (aa, 3), (cc, 1)
```

And with `f = (a, b) => a + 1`:

```
val intermediate1 = f((aa, 1), (bb, 1))       // (aa, 2)
val intermediate2 = f((aa, 1), (cc, 1))       // (aa, 1), (cc, 1)

// this is where it goes wrong:
val result = f(intermediate2, intermediate1)  // (aa, 2), (cc, 1)
```

Main thing is - order of intermediate calculations isn't guaranteed and may change between executions, and for the latter case of non-commutative function this means result are sometimes wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tzach for the clarification, but then this should hold true every time right?
Why am I getting correct result on some runs?

Comment: @Tzach I feel the 2nd case here would yield the same result. It will give a different result  if in last step val result = f(intermediate2, intermediate1) happens which would result to //(aa, 2), (cc, 1). Please let me know if I am wrong here

Comment: Is it that when intermediate1(a say in partition) and intermediate2(b say in partition) reaches the driver they may get shuffled.

intermediate1 becomes b and intermediate2 becomes a ? 
and thus instead of 
val result = f(intermediate1, intermediate2) it becomes
val result = f(intermediate2, intermediate1) and thus 1+1 ==2 and not 
2+1==3

Comment: Both comments correct - the need for commutativity and associativity stems from the fact the order is not guaranteed. I'll update the answer accordingly - messed up the example :)

Answer (score 3):

The function (a , b) => (a + 1) fails to be associative in nature. 
The associative law says,

```
f(a ,f(b , c)) = f(f(a , b), c)
```

Assume the below keys:

```
a = (x, 1)
b = (x, 1)
c = (x, 1)
```

Applying the function (a , b) => (a + 1)

```
f(a ,f(b , c)) = (x , 2)
```

But,

```
f(f(a , b), c) = (x , 3)
```

Hence, it is not associative and is not applicable for reduceByKey.